# Помогите сохранить вывод из консоли python re в txt

Tags: python, строки, консоль

```
import re

with open('ip1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.read()

regex = r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{3}'

finalT = re.findall(regex, text)

with open("out.txt", "w") as file:
    print(finalT, file=file, sep='\n')
```

Скрипт отрабатывает отлично, проблема в том что sep='\n' не отрабатывает и результат записывается в одну строку. Помогите пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Comment: `print(*finalT, file=file, sep='\n')` - поставьте звездочку перед `finalT`

Comment: Спасибооооооо, снимаю шляпу))))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(finalT, file=file, sep='\n')
```

Вы печатает один елементу, а `sep` заработает только если будет несколько элементов. Вам надо распокавать `finalT`

```
print(*finalT, file=file, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Спасибооооооо, снимаю шляпу))))))))